# Golang goroutine-safe http client with different timeout?

Tags: go, goroutine

Suppose I have the following function:

```
func SendRequest(c *Client, timeout time.Duration) {
  if timeout > 0 {
    c.Timeout = timeout
  } else {
    c.Timeout = defaultTimeout
  }
  ...
}
```

I want to allow multiple go-routines to call this function (to share the same HTTP client), but the way this is written apparently can't guarantee goroutine safety. (Also changing the timeout of the client passed in is weird too...)

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this. Should I use different client for different timeouts? Should I use some mutex? Or in general how do I share a HTTP client with different timeouts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different Clients. Even if you protect your function with a mutex, you can't protect the internal access by the Client, and another goroutine could change it while making the request.

Multiple Clients can still share the same Transport, and they both will use the DefaultTransport if you don't specify one.

Comment: So for HTTP in Go, which part is expensive so that we should reuse as much as possible, if any, and why?

Comment: @Danqing: What do you mean "which part is expensive"? Client and Transport- and what do you mean by "expensive"? Everything has a cost, so reuse what you can. For example, the Transport is where the connections are handled, hence using a single transport increases the likelihood of reusing connections.

Comment: Is this correct? From the [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) documentation: _"Clients and Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only be created once and re-used."_

Comment: @mjturner, you can use a client concurrently, but you cannot modify it concurrently.

Comment: @JimB Ah, gotcha - makes sense.